# Oracle : date not valid for month specified

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

i am trying to insert a record in oracle using toad and getting the error. As seen below i am using the TO_DATE FUNCTION

date not valid for month specified. I am using TO_DATE function.

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO MGR.TRACK_RECORD (VALUE_DATE,PERFORMANCE,DATE_CREATED,LAST_MODIFIED,CREATED_BY_ID,LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID,IS_ESTIMATE) 
                        VALUES (TO_DATE('2011/11/31 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),4.10,SYSDATE,SYSDATE,96,338,0)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: How many days are there in November?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear in that it states the date you provided (the day part, the 31st) is not valid for the month you provided (11, November). November only has 30 days.